# How can I skip deleting folders except a specified folder for a web deploy (msdeploy) sync?

Tags: regex, msdeploy, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

Suppose I have a *destination* folder structure that looks like this:

```
D:\DEPLOY\DEST
│   0.txt
│
├───a
│       a.txt
│
└───b
    ├───b1
    │   │   b1.txt
    │   │
    │   ├───b1a
    │   │       b1a.txt
    │   │
    │   └───b1b
    │           b1b.txt
    │
    └───b2
            b2.txt
```

I also have a *source* folder structure that looks like this:

```
D:\DEPLOY\SOURCE
└───b
    └───b1
        └───b1a
                b1a-new.txt
```

I would like to synchronize the *source* to the *destination*, but only below the `\b\\b1\b1a` path. To do that, when running MSDeploy, I add a skip rule matching all dirPaths not containing this path:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync 
         -source:contentPath=D:\deploy\source
         -dest:contentPath=D:\deploy\dest
         -skip:skipAction=delete,objectName=dirPath,absolutePath='(?!\\b\\b1\\b1a)'
         -whatif
```

resulting in:

```
Info: Deleting file (D:\deploy\dest\0.txt).
Info: Deleting file (D:\deploy\dest\b\b1\b1.txt).
Info: Adding file (D:\deploy\dest\b\b1\b1a\b1a-new.txt).
Info: Deleting file (D:\deploy\dest\b\b1\b1a\b1a.txt).
Total changes: 4 (1 added, 3 deleted, 0 updated, 0 parameters changed, 0 bytes copied)
```

To my surprise, this does more than expected. MSDeploy also deletes the files `0.txt` and `b1.txt`, which are under a dirPath that I expect to be skipped based on the regex. I tried various permutations of the absolutePath regex, but to no avail.

What should I be doing instead? Or is this beyond the possibilities of msdeploy?

**Note**: this example is simplified. In reality my source is package, not a contentPath. That is why the obvious answer of syncing at the `b\b1\b1a`-level would not apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've specified that you don't want it to delete *directories* outside that folder, but your skip rule says nothing about files. Just remove `,objectName=dirPath` from your skip directive and it will skip deletes on any provider.

As an aside, skip rules are actually quite nuanced in their behavior. I have a blog post that digs into it which might help: [Demystifying MSDeploy skip rules](https://blog.richardszalay.com/2012/12/17/demystifying-msdeploy-skip-rules/)

Comment: Your demystifying article is really helpful. Thank you.